# React and Redux: Pulling Data From Payload of Action Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

Did not get the help I was looking for in my previous question. I will try to ask it differently. DELETE_ITEM action type comes with a payload and if I console.log it, it displays the id number of the item being deleted. Now, only upon DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS I want to delete it from the state. DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS does not come with a payload. How can I get the payload from GET_ITEM which is the id number and use it in DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
//Action types
export const getItems = () => ({
  type: GET_ITEMS
});

export const updateItems = (data) => ({
  type   : UPDATE_ITEMS,
  payload: data
});

export const deleteItem = (itemId) => ({
  type   : DELETE_ITEM,
  payload: itemId
});
```

```
//Delete Api
export const apiDeleteRequest = (url, onSuccess, onError) => ({
  type: DELETE_API_REQUEST,
  meta: {url, onSuccess, onError}
});
```

```
//Middleware
export const removeItemFlow = ({dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {
  next(action);

  if(action.type === DELETE_ITEM){
      console.log(action.payload)
      dispatch(apiDeleteRequest(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${action.payload}`, DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS, DELETE_ITEM_ERROR));

  }
  if(action.type === DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS){
    console.log(action.payload)
    dispatch(updateItems(getState().items.itemsList.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)))
  }
};
```

Comment: What does `apiDeleteRequest` look like?

Comment: Nick, please see my updated code above. I added apiDeleteRequest code

Comment: Hmm, this is a very different pattern than I have ever seen. `apiDeleteRequest` looks like a middleware and it's being dispatched?

Comment: Sorry Nick, that was a mistake. I copied the middleware code. I corrected it above

Comment: Are you averse to passing the ID as a separate arugment to your `apiDeleteRequest` function? That's probably what I'd do with this architecture, otherwise you need to set it in your state somewhere to retrieve it later, and I can envision that being a mess with async things going on.

Comment: Did not think of that. That's actually a better approach. How can I then use the ID in the IF statement where it checks to see DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS?

Comment: It makes every bit of sense that the `DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS` action payload also contains the deleted item id. Why don't you just include it there?

Comment: Wherever you actually dispatch the `DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS` action you can simply include the `id` as the payload

Comment: I must add that, the middleware you've just showed us is the perfect place to actually HANDLE `DELETE_API_REQUEST` and `DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS`, instead of further `dispatch()` these actions to some where else. If you just handle them right inside the middleware, your whole problem is gone.

Comment: Nick and hackape thank you so much. That worked for me and successfully executed my desired task. Don't know why I did not think of that before. With frustration common sense goes out the window. Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the enhancement that could be done to the middleware, which I mentioned in the comment beneath question. My proposition is to handle the API call right inside the middleware, instead of further dispatching the action and delegate the handling to some other code.

```js
export const removeItemFlow = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
  next(action);

  if (action.type === DELETE_ITEM) {
    const itemIdToDelete = action.payload

    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${action.payload}`
    const onSuccessCallback = () => {
      // do whatever you would do when DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS
      console.log('You get access to "itemIdToDelete" right here', itemIdToDelete)
      dispatch(updateItems(getState().items.itemsList.filter(item => item.id !== itemIdToDelete)))
    }
    const onErrorCallback = () => {
      // do whatever you would do when DELETE_ITEM_ERROR
      console.log('You get access to "itemIdToDelete" right here', itemIdToDelete)
    }

    axios.delete(url).then(onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)
};
```